# Need any information about an affine lattice

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, lattices

Motivation - I was thinking about calculating the integrals from [An interesting integral expression for $\pi^n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/267485/41291) using old plain Riemann sums. There, one needs integrating over that part of $[0,1]^n$ where the coordinates are more than $\varepsilon$ apart from each other, so I thought maybe I can choose a grid for the multidimensional Riemann integral with these $\varepsilon$s somehow built in.

Then a natural thing to try is this:
$$
\left\{(k_1,...,k_n)\in\mathbb Z^n\mid k_i\ne k_j\mod n\text{ for $i\ne j$}\right\}
$$
(and then scale down to $\varepsilon$)

The above set is clearly a(n affine) lattice. Have you seen it before? What symmetries does it have? Is it listed in any nomenclature and how to find it?

Specifically I would like to have a more manageable enumeration of this lattice, - say, a nice basis. All bases I can think of are very unnatural, break symmetry terribly and result in messy formulas when I am trying to calculate anything with them.

Comment: Two questions. First, you are using $n$ for both the dimension of your space and for the modulus. I'll assume that's a mistake and let $m$ denote the modulus. Second, what do you mean by an "affine lattice"? Your set is clearly not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$, so not a lattice. For example, for $n=2$, the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are in your set, but their sum is not.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I would be interested to know about the case when the modulus differs from the dimension but the case when they are equal suffices for me. It is sort of minimal.

Comment: Affine lattices occur frequently, but I am not sure which terminology for them is established. Simplest definition probably is that it is a shift by some vector of a lattice in the ordinary sense.

Comment: In terms of closure under sums, it is equivalent to define affine lattices as subsets closed under $(x,y,z)\mapsto x-y+z$ and finitely generated (in the appropriate sense)