# A closed form for an integral expressed as a finite series of $\zeta(2k+1)$, $\pi^m$ and a rational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function, mathematical-software

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.3602.pdf) the following beautiful integral expression for $\zeta(3)$ is derived:

$$\zeta(3)=\frac{1}{7}\,\int_0^{\pi} x\,(\pi-x)\csc(x)\, dx$$

In a comment at the end of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267485/an-interesting-integral-expression-for-pin), I mentioned the following tweak:

$$f(n):= \int_0^{\pi} x^n\,(\pi-x)\csc(x)\,dx$$

Maple and Mathematica both return closed forms for $f(n)$ as a finite series of $\zeta(2k+1)$, weighted by $π^m$ and a rational ($n,k,m \in \mathbb{N}$). This is what I get for $n=1..12$ :

[image]

I then tried to find a closed form for the above and got as far as:

For $n=$ odd:
$$f(n)=\scriptsize \left(\Gamma(n+1)\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\,\frac{(4-2^{1-2k})\,k\,\pi^{n+1-2k}}{\Gamma(2+n-2k)}\,\zeta(2k+1)\right)-\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{n+1}\,(2^{n+2}-1)\,\Gamma(n+2)\,\zeta(n+2)$$

For $n=$ even:
$$f(n)=\scriptsize \left(\Gamma(n+1)\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\,\frac{(4-2^{1-2k})\,k\,\pi^{n+1-2k}}{\Gamma(2+n-2k)}\,\zeta(2k+1)\right)+\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^{n}\,(2^{n+1}-1)\,\pi\,\Gamma(n+1)\,\zeta(n+1)$$

Note that only the last part differs, which encourages me to believe that a simpler formula might exist. Could this be simplified? Since the CAS-tools evaluate the integral very quickly into the series, I am also keen to better understand which mathematical steps they take.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify this any further, in view of the linear independence of the list $\{\zeta(2k+1)\}$.

Comment: @T.A, that linear independence is hypothesized, not proved, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, but overwhelmingly correct.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan What do you mean with "overwhelmingly correct"? Is there any more evidence to it than the fact we have not found any linear relation between them?

Comment: Clarification: it seems more likely true than not.

Comment: I have just seen this question and feel that it is potentially relevant to link this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437032/tough-integral-int-0-pi-fracx2-pi-x2-sin2-x-dx-6-pi-zeta3).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the following articles can give a clue:
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10652460701688125?journalCode=gitr20 (Closed-form evaluation of some families of cotangent and cosecant integrals, by D. Cvijović) and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702003588 (Integral representations of the Riemann zeta function for odd-integer arguments, by D. Cvijović and J. Klinowski).

**Update**. In particular, using $2x^n=E_n(x)+E_n(1+x)$ and $E_n(1+x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}E_k(x)$, we get
$$f(n)=\frac{\pi^{n+2}}{2}\left[I_n+\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}I_k-I_{n+1}-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}I_k\right]=\frac{\pi^{n+2}}{2}\left[I_n-2I_{n+1}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k-1}I_k\right], \tag{1}$$
where $$I_n=\int\limits_0^1E_n(x)\csc{(\pi x)}\,dx.$$
Odd indices in (1) doesn't contribute because $E_n(1-x)=(-1)^nE_n(x)$ leads to the integrand which is antisymmetric with regard to $x\to 1-x$. For even indices, $I_n$ was calculated in the second paper indicated above as $$I_{2n}=(-1)^n\frac{(4-2^{1-2n})(2n)!}{\pi^{2n+1}}\zeta(2n+1),$$ and we obtain, for even $n=2m$:
$$f(2m)=(-1)^m\frac{\pi}{2}(4-2^{1-2m})(2m)!\,\zeta(2m+1)- \sum\limits_{p=1}^m(-1)^p\;\frac{\pi^{2(m-p)+1}}{2}\;\binom{2m}{2p-1}(4-2^{1-2p})(2p)!\,\zeta(2p+1),$$
and for odd $n=2m-1, m>1$:
$$f(2m-1)=(-1)^{m+1}(4-2^{1-2m})(2m)!\,\zeta(2m+1)-\sum\limits_{p=1}^{m-1}(-1)^p\;\frac{\pi^{2(m-p)}}{2}\;\binom{2m-1}{2p-1}(4-2^{1-2p})(2p)!\,\zeta(2p+1).$$

Comment: Many thanks, Zurab. I have tested your now proven formulae  and they work perfectly!

Comment: I found some further simplification is possible using the Heaviside step function: $$\Theta(n)= 
     \begin{cases}
     1  &\quad n \ge 0\\
      0&\quad n < 0  \\
     \end{cases}$$

For $n=$ even: $$f(m)=\Gamma(m+1)\,\sum_{p=1}^{\frac{m}{2}} \left(\tfrac{m-1}{m}\right)^{\Theta\left(p-\frac{m}{2}\right)}  (-1)^{p+1}\,\frac{\pi^{m+1-2p}\,p\,(4-2^{1-2p})}{\Gamma(m+2-2p)}\,\zeta(2p+1)$$

For $n=$ odd: $$f(m)=\Gamma(m+1)\,\sum_{p=1}^{\frac{m}{2}+\frac12}\, \,2^{\Theta\left(p-\frac{m}{2}-\frac12\right)}  \,\,(-1)^{p+1}\,\frac{\pi^{m+1-2p}\,p\,(4-2^{1-2p})}{\Gamma(m+2-2p)}\,\zeta(2p+1)$$

Comment: Made a typo: For $ n=$ even/odd should of course be: For $m=$ even/odd.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but... *Mathematica* evaluates the indefinite integral
$$\int x^k \csc x d x$$ in terms of polylogs, from which your integral follows readily, so the obvious question is - how does it do the indefinite integral. The short answer is: [The Risch algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Risch_algorithm) (or, more precisely, an extension, since the original algorithm only deals with elementary antiderivatives). However, if you want to do it by hand, the two methods which come to mind are:

1. Make the substitution $u = \exp(i x),$ which transforms your integrand into a power of log times a rational function - this is plausbible, since the arguments of the polylogs have the form $\exp(i x),$ so *Mathematica* might, indeed, be doing this.
2. Expand $\csc x$ in its Laurent series around $0,$ and integrate term by term. The Laurent series is explicit (in terms of Bernoulli numbers), so it may be that a simple manipulation gets it to your linear combination of zetas (I haven't tried).

Comment: Many thanks, Igor. Great suggestions that I will pursue. Mathematica seems to indeed firstly evaluate the integral in terms of polylogs and then to run a FullSimplify to reduce it to the series with the $\zeta(2k+1)$s. I tried to find other integrals that have this "reduction"-property, but so far only found: $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \big(x\,\csc(x)\big)^n\,dx$$ that only for even $n$ reduces to combinations of $\pi^k$, $\ln(2)$ and $\zeta(2k+1)$. E.g. for $n=2$ we get $\pi\,\ln(2)$ and for $n=4$ we get: $\frac{1}{12}\pi\,\left(-\pi^2-18\,\zeta(3)+4\,\pi^2\,\ln(2)+24\,\ln(2)\right)$, etc.

Comment: @Agno: The formula for that integral is e.g. here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786281/generalised-integral-i-n-displaystyle-int-0-pi-2-fracxn-sin-n-x/1859150#1859150

Comment: @user90369 Many thanks for that link. Much appreciated. I had completely missed that discussion on MSE. In the mean time I also derived (a more complicated) formula here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273375/another-integral-that-has-a-closed-form-involving-finite-series-of-zeta2k1?noredirect=1&lq=1 Does your formula also work for $n < 0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, the formula doesn't work for $n<0$ it was only an answer to the question. :-) 
*Perhaps it's useful to formulate a separate question about $\int\limits_0^z x^m \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n dx$ with $m\geq 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ .*