# Another integral that has a closed form involving finite series of $\zeta(2k+1)$'s. Could it be reflexive?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function, integer-sequences

In the context of a series of questions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270286/a-closed-form-for-an-integral-expressed-as-a-finite-series-of-zeta2k1-p), [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271001/are-these-two-new-ways-of-representing-odd-zeta-values-as-integrals-known) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271526/is-there-a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-tanh3xx2dx), about closed form expressions involving finite series of $\zeta(2k+1)$'s for certain integrals, I would like to raise another one:

$$f(n):=\int\limits_0^1\bigg(\frac{\pi x}{2}\,\csc\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\bigg)^{2n}dx$$

Various CAS-tools induce closed forms at integer values. Below are the ones for $n=4 \dots-4$:

[image]

where $Si(x)$= the [Sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

I managed to find (numerically, not a direct derivation) generic formulae for all rational coefficients in these closed forms for both $n\ge1$ and $n\le 1$. They are listed in the greyed area below.

**Question:**

Could this integral be reflexive, i.e. could or does there exist a functional relation between for instance $f(n)$ and $f(-n)$ (and thereby potentially relating the $\zeta(2k+1)$'s to the $Si(k)$'s)?

$\\$
$\\$
$\\$

> $\rightarrow$ for $n=1,2,3,...$:
>
> \begin{align} \small f(n) &=\small
>  2n\cdot\sum_{q=1}^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^{q}(-1)^r\frac{CFN(n,q)}{\Gamma(2\,(q-r+1))}\frac{2^{2r}-1}{2^{2r}}\,{\color{blue}{\zeta(2r+1)\,\pi^{2(q-r)}}}\\
>  &+\small2n\cdot
>  \sum_{q=0}^{n-1}\frac{CFN(n,q)}{\Gamma(2\,(q+1))}\,{\color{blue}{\ln(2)\,\pi^{2q}}}\\
>  &+2n\cdot\frac{ETA1(n-1)}{\Gamma(2n)}\,{\color{blue}{\pi^{2(n-1)}}}\\
>  &+2n\cdot\small\sum_{q=1}^{n-2}(-1)^{n-q}\,\frac{ETA(n,n-q)}{\Gamma(2\,(q+1))}\,{\color{blue}{\pi^{2q}}}\\
>   \end{align}
>
> $\displaystyle \scriptsize CFN(n,k) = \sum_{m=-k}^{k}(-1)^m\,s(n,n+m-k)\,s(n,n-m-k)$
>
> This is the Central Factorial Number triangle ([A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955)) with $s(p,q)=$ [first kind Stirling number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).
>
> $\displaystyle \scriptsize ETA1(n) \,\, = -\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{n!}{k!}\right)^2\,\frac{\Gamma(2k)}{2^{2k}}$
>
> $\displaystyle \scriptsize ETA(n,k) =(-1)^{k}\,\sum_{m=1}^{n-k}coeff\left(\prod_{p=m+2}^{n-1}(1+p^2x),x,n-k-m\right)\,ETA1(m) \quad k>1,n>k$
>
> with *coeff*$(gf,x,k)=$ the k-th coefficient of generating function $gf(x)$. $ETA(n,k)$ is directly related to the Eta-triangle [A160464](https://oeis.org/A160464), e.g.$2^{2+\log_{2}(n)}\,ETA1[n]=$[A160465](https://oeis.org/A160465).
>
> $\\$
>   $\\$
>
> $\rightarrow$ for $n=-1,-2,-3,...$: 
>   \begin{align} \small f(-n) &=\small
>  4n \sum_{q=1}^{n}(-1)^{q+n}\,\frac{q^{2n-1}}{(n-q)!\,(n+q)!}\,{\color{blue}{\frac{Si(q\,\pi)}{\pi}}}\\
>  &-\frac{2^{2n}}{(2n-1)}\,{\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\pi^{2n}}}}\\
> &+\small
>  \frac{n}{\Gamma(2n)}\sum_{q=1}^{n-1}\,(-1)^{q+1}\,2^{2n-q}\,\Gamma(2n-2q-1)\left(\sum_{r=0}^{q}(-1)^{r+q+1}ETT(q,r+1)\,n^r\right){\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\pi^{2(n-q)}}}}\\
>   \end{align}
>
> $\displaystyle \scriptsize ETT(n,m) = \frac{1}{2^{n-m}}\,\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{s(k,m)\,\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\,(-1)^{n+m+i}\,(i-k)^{2n}\,\binom{2k}{i}}{2^{k-1}\,k!}$ which is [A083061](https://oeis.org/A083061).

Comment: I just came about your nice question. Wow, lots of work already involved! For better readability, could you please re-arrange the terms for $n=-4..4$, such that their order corresponds to your general formula, preferably writing each sum with decreasing orders/arguments? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks and great suggestion Wolfgang. I will follow up today and re-post. Intuitively I do believe there is more to simplify in these formulae as well. Especially since the $\pi^{2k}$ terms seem related to the Dirichlet $\eta(s)$ function, I actually do expect $\zeta(2k)$'s to emerge somewhere as well and/or maybe even $\zeta'(-2k)$'s (but haven't found a direct connection yet).

Comment: OK. It is just $\zeta'(-2k)=\dfrac{(2k)!}{\pi^{2k}}\dfrac{\zeta(2k+1)}{2^{2k+1}}$ which won't simplify the formulae a lot.

Comment: I think for $n<0$ the occurrences of $Si(q\pi)$ (and probably all the rest) can be easily explained by applying integration by parts and possibly multiple angle formulae. Note that e.g. $f(-1)=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\sin^2 z}{z^2}dz=\frac2\pi\left[\frac{2 z Si(2 z) + \cos(2 z) - 1}{2z}\right]_{z=0}^{z=\frac\pi2}=\frac2\pi(Si(\pi)-\frac2\pi)$.  So there are hardly any chances for a deeper link with the odd zeta values occurring for $n>0$.

Comment: Great insight, Wolfgang. Do you know where the $\ln(2)$ could come from for $n>1$?

Comment: No, I haven't, but supposing you know where it "comes from" for n=1 (If ever that can be "found out" in some well defined way, which I'd rather doubt), it will of course be similar for higher powers. Usually it should be obtainable by some series expansion I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in my comment, there is no link between $f(n)$ for $n<0$ and the odd zeta values occurring for $n>0$.

For $n<0$, putting $k:=-n>0$, we have  $f(-k)=\dfrac2\pi\int\limits_0^{\frac\pi2}\dfrac{\sin^{2k} z}{z^{2k} }dz$. After one integration by parts, we remain with some negative power of $\pi$ and an integral $\int \limits_0^{\frac\pi2}\dfrac{\sin^{2k-1} z\cos z}{z^{2k-1} }dz.$
Performing $2k-2$ more integrations by parts, all the remaining integrals are a combination $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_j\int\limits_0^{\frac\pi2} \dfrac{\sin^{2j-1} z\cos z}{z  }dz.$$
By the multiple angle formulae, we can  write the numerators as linear combinations of $\sin 2rz$ with $r=1,...,j$, thus evaluating the integrals as multiples of $Si(\pi),...,Si(k\pi)$.

As an example,  $f(-1)=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\sin^2 z}{z^2}dz=\frac2\pi\left[\frac{2 z Si(2 z) + \cos(2 z) - 1}{2z}\right]_{z=0}^{z=\frac\pi2}=\frac2\pi(Si(\pi)-\frac2\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Wolfgang. I had two hints that led me to believe a reflexive relation might exist: 

1) The ETA ($n \ge 1$) and ETT ($n \le1$) as coefficients for the $\pi^{\pm k}$s seem related. The ETT triangle is also represented here: https://oeis.org/A094665. The comment under this series by Johannes W. Meijer indicates there is a direct link to the ETA triangle listed here https://oeis.org/A160464. They both seem to originate from the "ES1 matrix" that in turn is related to the Dirichlet $\eta$-function. The connection is difficult to unravel though.

Comment: 2) In the beautiful answer by T. Amdeberhan to one of your related questions https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271526/is-there-a-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-tanh3xx2dx, he derives the following divergent series formula for negative $c$: $$\sum_{k\geq2}(-1)^ck^c\log k=-\zeta'(-c)(2^{c+1}-1)+\zeta(-c)2^{c+1}\log2$$. Could the appearance of $\log(2)$ in this formula be related to the $\log(2)$ appearing in my question above?

Comment: @Agno Of course it is always difficult to decide in which way the occurrences of log(2) in two formulae can be "related". Well, I am a bit like you in that I am always interested in exploring deeper, underlying connections. What you say about ETA and ETT reminds me of Stirling numbers of 1st and 2nd kind: If you write both kinds as infinite matrices, one is the inverse of the other, yet the ways they occur e.g. in generating functions is very different. I haven't checked if the ETA triangle is the inverse of the ETT (maybe up to some diagonal matrix), but I wouldn't be surprised if it is!