# A tricky integral to evaluate

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, elementary-proofs

I came across this integral in some work. So, I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Can you evaluate this integral with proofs?
> $$\int_0^1\frac{\log x\cdot\log(x+2)}{x+1}\,dx.$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a closed-form solution.

Comment: I think it is bad form silently to edit your question to ask for proofs, after @CarloBeenakker already gave an [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385259) to the original version that did not request proofs. (That doesn't mean you can't ask for proofs, just that I think it's polite to point out that that is a new request.)

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker and all: I apologize for the edit. I was always under the impression that when you evaluate something, you also give a proof. But, that was not happening earlier, so to clarify I added "with proof".

Comment: This is actually non-trivial: WolframAlpha's closed form for the definite integral has no proof, and Mathematica's closed form for the indefinite integral is complex and not easy to use at 0 or 1.

Comment: Is there a nice expression for some $f(x)$ with $f'(x)=\log(x)\log(x+2)/(x+1)$ which is obviously real on $0<x<1$? I have not been able to get one out of Mathematica.

Comment: @LSpice: I do not think that answers without proofs for such questions belong on MathOverflow in the first place, so editing the question to indicate this implicitly understood convention is not bad form.

Comment: I'd split the difference between LSpice and Dmitri by saying that answers which are just numbers you got from computer software are okay, in so far as they can certainly be helpful for getting a complete solution, but that asking for a better answer with a true proof is totally reasonable too.

Comment: For what it's worth, $\int_0^1 (\log x)^2/(x+1) dx = \tfrac32 \zeta(3)$ is easily found by series expansion of the denominator.

Comment: Maybe we should talk about the fact this is integral of 2 ln(f) / f' ?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1344455).

Comment: @RichardBirkett Please note that the two logs are multiplied, not added^^

Answer (score 11):

For $t\in(0,1]$, let
\begin{equation}
    I(t):=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)\,\log(1+t(x+1))}{x+1}\,dx 
\end{equation}
(so that the integral in question is $I(1)$),
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    J(t)&:=-\text{Li}_3(2+1/t)+\text{Li}_3(-2 t-1)+\text{Li}_3(t+1) \\ 
    &-\text{Li}_3(2t+1) 
   +\text{Li}_2(2+1/t) (\log (2 t+1)+i \pi ) \\ 
   &+\text{Li}_2(-2 t-1)(-\log (2 t+1)-i \pi ) \\ 
   &+\text{Li}_2(t+1) (-\log (t+1)-i \pi )+\text{Li}_2(2 t+1) (\log (2
   t+1)+i \pi ) \\ 
   &+\frac{1}{6} (\log ^3(t)+(-3 \log ^2(t+1)-6 i \pi  \log (t+1)+4 \pi
   ^2) \log (t) \\ 
   &+3 \pi  (-i \log ^2(t+1)+2 i \log ^2(2 t+1)+2 \pi  \log (t+1)-4
   \pi  \log (2 t+1))) \\ 
   &+\frac{3 \zeta (3)}{4}-\frac{5 i \pi ^3}{12}, 
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I_1(t)&:=6tI'(t)=6t\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{1+t(x+1)}\,dx \\ 
&   =6 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{t+1}{2 t+1}\right)-3 \log ^2(t+1)+3 \log ^2(2 t+1) \\ 
&+6 \log (t) \log
   \left(\frac{t+1}{2 t+1}\right)-\pi ^2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    J_1(t)&:=6tJ'(t)=6 \text{Li}_2\left(2+1/t\right)+3 \log ^2(t)-3 \log ^2(t+1) \\ 
    &-6 (\log (2 t+1)+i \pi )
   \log (t)+6 \log (t+1) \log (2 t+1) \\ 
   &+6 i \pi  \log (2 t+1)-2 \pi ^2. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then $I'_1=J'_1$ and $I_1(0+)=J_1(0+)$, so that $I_1=J_1$, and hence $I'=J'$. Also, $I(0)=I(0+)=0=J(0+)$, so that $I=J$, and the integral in question is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I(1)&=J(1)=\text{Li}_3(-3)-2 \text{Li}_3(3)+i \pi  \left(-\text{Li}_2(-3)+2 \text{Li}_2(3)+\log
   ^2(3)\right) \\ 
   &-\text{Li}_2(-3) \log (3)+\text{Li}_2(3) \log (9)+\frac{13 \zeta
   (3)}{8}-\frac{2 i \pi ^3}{3}-\pi ^2 \log (9) \\
   &=-0.651114\dots.  
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}

Comment: Educated guessing vs. "backward pioneering"...

Answer (score 7):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\cdot\ln(x+2)}{x+1}\,dx=$$
$$=\text{Li}_3\left(-\tfrac{1}{3}\right)-2 \,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)+\tfrac{1}{2} \ln 3\left[ \text{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{1}{9}\right)-6\, \text{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)  -\tfrac{2}{3} \ln ^2 3\right]+\tfrac{13}{8} \zeta (3).$$
I checked that this combination of polylog's evaluates to $-0.651114$, equal to a numerical evaluation of the integral.

Update:
As Timothy Budd pointed out, that this combination of polylog's simplifies to $-\frac{13}{24}\zeta(3)$ is proven by Przemo at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3237266/87355).
The identities that enable this simplification are
$$\text{Li}_3\left(-\tfrac{1}{3}\right)-2 \,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right) = -\tfrac{1}{6} \ln^3 3 + \tfrac{1}{6}\pi^2 \ln 3 - \tfrac{13}{6} \zeta(3),$$
$$\text{Li}_2(\tfrac{1}{9})=2\,\text{Li}_2(-\tfrac{1}{3})+2\,\text{Li}_2(\tfrac{1}{3}),$$
$$2\text{Li}_2\left(-\tfrac{1}{3}\right)-4 \,\text{Li}_2\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right) =
\ln^2 3 -\tfrac{1}{3}\pi^2 .$$

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to eliminate the imaginary parts?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: is there an even simpler answer and proof?

Comment: I computed numerically that the value is $-\frac{13\zeta(3)}{24}$, so it seems. Hope this shades some light into the problem.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: On 18 April 2017 you knew already (with proof) that the integral equals $-\frac{13\zeta(3)}{24}$. See your own response at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267485/an-interesting-integral-expression-for-pin So it is not clear why you say that "I computed numerically etc." Of course it is legitimate and useful to ask for simpler proofs.

Comment: Do you have a proof of the first display (other than what we can learn from Iosif Pinelis's answer and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344455/proving-that-int-01-frac-log-left-frac1t-right-log-t2t1-d)? I mean, where did you get the first display from?

Comment: @GHfromMO: Thank you, this is helpful. I completely forgot about this encounter.