# What should motives for $L(E,n)$ look like?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives, l-functions

Goncharov and Manin showed [in this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0204102) that the zeta values $\zeta(n)$ can be realized as periods of framed mixed Tate motives constructed from moduli spaces $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n+3}$ of rational curves.  (See also [this MO-question for a discussion.)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172013/)
I would like to know if analogous statements are expected (or maybe even known?) for special values of $L$-functions of elliptic curves.

So let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$ and $L(E,s)$ its associated Hasse-Weil $L$-function. If $E$ is modular, then Beilinson's theorem tells us that the special values $L(E,n)$ for $n\geq 2$ are periods, see e.g. [this MO-question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54237/) So it is, in principle, possible to write $L(E,n)$ as integral of a rational differential form over some cycle in an algebraic variety (roughly).

- Can the corresponding variety be made more explicit (ideally as explicit as in the work of Goncharov and Manin)? Has there been any work in this direction?
- What should framed motives realizing $L(E,n)$ look like?

(I know there is a [paper by Brown and Levin](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6917) on multiple elliptic polylogarithms, based on configuration spaces of marked points on the elliptic curve. However, motives realizing elliptic polylogarithms do not seem to be explicitly discussed in the paper.)

- Could we expect framed motives realizing special values $L(E,n)$ to be constructed from configuration spaces of points on $E$?

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider first an analogous case of a number field $F$. Then it is  conjectured that special values of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_{F}(n)$ is a linear combination of multiple polylogarithms, evaluated at some configurations of points of $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ defined over $F$. Multiple polylogarithms are periods of the pro-unipotent completion of a punctured projective line. This is a weakened version of Zagier conjecture, known for $n\leq 4.$

I think that similar statement is expected to hold in your case, with $\mathbb{P}^1$ substituted by the elliptic curve. [For $n=3$ it is known for modular elliptic curves.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9512016.pdf) The relation between the generalized Eisenstein-Kronecker and pro-unipotent completion of the fundamental group of punctured elliptic curve is explained [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0297.pdf) (theorem 11.9).